# How can I set maximum width of a view in iOS?

Tags: ios, autolayout

My app have a basic login screen, an outer box and in it, some text fields and buttons. I set the box to fill the screen. However, on some devices this box will be too big. How do I set maximum width and height to a view?

Comment: Does not matter, I can use anything. I would prefer doing in it storyboard. And yes I use autolayout.

Comment: Well you just set constraints for that box, left and right, to satisfy spacing. Fo example left and right constraint constants 20.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use auto-layout constraints so that the box adapts to the screen size, but does not exceed a given width and height. To do this, set a "less than or equal to" constraint on the width and height.

1. Add top, bottom, leading, trailing, width and height constraints to the box.
2. Set the priority of the top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to **High** (750).
3. Set the relation for the width and height constraints to **Less Than or Equal** (≤). The default value is **Equal**.
4. Set the priority of the width and height constraints to **Required** (1000).
5. Set the constant of the width and height constraints to the *maximum* size you want the box to be.

[image: Set width constraint relation to Less Than or Equal]

[image: Set width constraint constant to 1000]

[image: Set leading and trailing constraint priority to 750]

Comment: This looks ambiguous since how would auto layout know which constraint to break in case the height becomes more than the given constant. It could either break the top constraint sticking to the bottom of the screen or the bottom constraint sticking to the top. How is this working?

Comment: @Sikander This should be used with other constraints, such as a center constraint, to keep the view aligned.

Comment: This is a great solution. For anyone running into issues with UITextField not respecting the constraints set at 750, using 950 instead achieves the same result and solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this programmatically

```
some_view.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.45)        
some_view.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.widthAnchor multiplier: 0.45)
```

`0.45` is basically saying the width and height of some_view will be at maximum 45% of the width of the super view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a View's frame to fix all devices then use this `width` and `height`

`self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height`

Or You can give auto layouts `Top` `Bottom` `Trailing` and  `Leading constraints` by dragging the View to its edges.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you use only four constraints (i.e Top space,Bottom space,Leading space,Trailing space) for that container view.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Interface Builder you could :

- ctrl + clic your view and drag the blue arrow to the superview.
- Hold shift and select "equal width" and "equal height"
- Then go to the constraints of your view (little ruler icon) and set a multiplier like 0.5 to make your view width/height equal to half of its superview respective dimension.

Answer (score -3):

```
UIView *viw=[UIView alloc]init];
viw.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,CGFLOAT_MAX,h);
```

Comment: setting the frame is different than applying constraints.

Comment: @rvios Please add some explanation to your code. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score -5):

**Try following code it may helps you**

```
yourviewObject.frame=CGRectMake(yourviewObject.frame.origin.x,yourviewObject.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,yourviewObject.frame.size.height)
```