# iOS Autolayout | View's height anchor

Tags: ios, swift3, autolayout, height, anchor

I'm using **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** to calculate cells height.
In my custom cell, height depends on it's content (text).
So i need to layout UIImageView height. I need to set UIImageView maximum height to some constant. But when text is short UIImageView's height becomes smaller to fit its superview with inset.
[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMKyg.png)
[Needs to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSaBz.png)
**Playground code example:**

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let descriptions = ["", "Curabitur.", "Senectus sit consectetur fermentum nisi suspendisse a condimentum at vestibulum a vestibulum a nostra fermentum molestie sodales molestie id viverra scelerisque consectetur.Penatibus a dictum metus mus commodo a hac morbi parturient parturient convallis ultrices a mi id.Fringilla lobortis suspendisse vestibulum quisque consectetur imperdiet.", "Condimentum adipiscing.", "Cras scelerisque parturient vitae class sollicitudin.", "Integer adipiscing a adipiscing parturient tempus condimentum a interdum facilisis feugiat.", "Donec eros eleifend a ullamcorper class scelerisque nisi nullam nisi sociis ante iaculis pharetra malesuada nibh sit consectetur condimentum.Nibh sollicitudin."]

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        tv.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tv.separatorStyle = .none
        tv.register(PrototypeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(PrototypeCell.self))
        return tv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
        tableView.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return descriptions.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(PrototypeCell.self), for: indexPath) as! PrototypeCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Title #\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = "Subtitle #\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = descriptions[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class PrototypeCell: UITableViewCell {

    let foregroundView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    let detailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.backgroundColor = .gray
        return iv
    }()

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.numberOfLines = 1
        lbl.text = "Title"
        return lbl
    }()

    let subtitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.numberOfLines = 1
        lbl.text = "Subtitile"
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        return lbl
    }()

    let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.numberOfLines = 0
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        return lbl
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        selectionStyle = .none

        contentView.addSubview(foregroundView)
        foregroundView.addSubview(detailImageView)
        foregroundView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        foregroundView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)
        foregroundView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                foregroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
                foregroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
                foregroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
                foregroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),

                detailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64),
                detailImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64),
                detailImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
                detailImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),

                titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
                titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),
                titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),

                subtitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 2),
                subtitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
                subtitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),

                descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subtitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 2),
                descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
                descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
                descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

var ctrl = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ctrl.view
```

**Thanks everyone!

Final solution:**

```
    //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let descriptions = [nil, "Curabitur.", "Senectus sit consectetur fermentum nisi suspendisse a condimentum at vestibulum a vestibulum a nostra fermentum molestie sodales molestie id viverra scelerisque consectetur.Penatibus a dictum metus mus commodo a hac morbi parturient parturient convallis ultrices a mi id.Fringilla lobortis suspendisse vestibulum quisque consectetur imperdiet.", "Condimentum adipiscing.", "Cras scelerisque parturient vitae class sollicitudin.", "Integer adipiscing a adipiscing parturient tempus condimentum a interdum facilisis feugiat.", "Donec eros eleifend a ullamcorper class scelerisque nisi nullam nisi sociis ante iaculis pharetra malesuada nibh sit consectetur condimentum.Nibh sollicitudin."]

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        tv.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tv.separatorStyle = .none
        tv.register(PrototypeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(PrototypeCell.self))
        return tv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
        tableView.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return descriptions.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(PrototypeCell.self), for: indexPath) as! PrototypeCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Title #\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = "Subtitle #\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = descriptions[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class PrototypeCell: UITableViewCell {

    let foregroundView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    let detailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.backgroundColor = .gray
        return iv
    }()

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.numberOfLines = 1
        lbl.text = "Title"
        return lbl
    }()

    let subtitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.numberOfLines = 1
        lbl.text = "Subtitile"
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        return lbl
    }()

    let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.numberOfLines = 0
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        return lbl
    }()

    var detailImageViewBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        detailImageViewBottomAnchor = detailImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4)
        detailImageViewBottomAnchor.priority = 749
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        selectionStyle = .none

        contentView.addSubview(foregroundView)
        foregroundView.addSubview(detailImageView)
        foregroundView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        foregroundView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)
        foregroundView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                foregroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
                foregroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
                foregroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
                foregroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),

                detailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 64),
                detailImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64),
                detailImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
                detailImageViewBottomAnchor,
                detailImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),

                titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
                titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),
                titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),

                subtitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 2),
                subtitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
                subtitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),

                descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subtitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 2),
                descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
                descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foregroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
                descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),

            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

var ctrl = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ctrl.view
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution which just works for me.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308811/3172726) solution to make it work.
All you have to do for your View.

1. Make your height constraint's **less than or equal** to a value(let's say,40) and priority default(1000)
2. Draw a bottom constraint which has **high priority(750)** and just give a value

And thats it.

This is how it looks.

[image]

And this is attribute of height constraint.

[image]

This is for bottom constraint.

[image]

This is my whole layout hierarchy(It's not important though just to let you know that you can use stack View for your text Label :))

[image]

And this is the output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all of your description, but i don't like using storyboards. And  that's not exactly what i want. I need to set max height of image and at the same time it should be smaller if text is short.

Comment: Oh, this work's but i changed bottom priority to 749. Seems like before (with 750 bottom priority) table view calculated height just for image view.

Answer (score 0):

In your PrototypeCell's `layoutSubviews()`  function add

```
  if self.view.frame.size.height < 68 {
        detailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.size.height - 8)
    } else {
    detailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64)
   }
```

Here if the cell height is less than 68 then the imageview height will be the cell height - 8. Where 8 being top space of imageview(4) + the bottom space of imageview(4).